# How to perform a reduction operation on some parts of a Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I've encountered a situation that I though possible to handle using the Stream API but I simply cannot figure out a proper solution.

The case is the following : I have a stream of elements sorted by an identifier field. There are several elements with the same value for this identifier, and I need to deduplicate them based on conditions on other fields. Conceptually, it can be seen as a reduce operation on several chunks of the stream yielding to a stream of the same type.

For now, the only solution I manage to come with, is to collect the stream based on the common identifier to obtain something like `Map<Id, List<Elem>>` and then use this map's stream to apply my deduplication rules and go on. The problem (and why I won't use this solution) is that `collect` is a terminal operation, re-streaming after it means that I will iterate over my elements twice.

**UPDATE**

Consider the following class :

```
public static class Item {
    private final int _id;
    private final double _price;

    public Item(final int id, final double price) {
        _id = id;
        _price = price;
    }

    public int id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public double price() {
        return _price;
    }
}
```

And the following stream :

```
final Stream<Item> items = Stream.<Item>builder()
        .add(new Item(1, 4))
        .add(new Item(1, 6))
        .add(new Item(1, 3))
        .add(new Item(2, 5))
        .add(new Item(2, 1))
        .add(new Item(3, 5))
        .build();
```

After the required operation, if the rule of deduplication is "with the highest price", the stream should only contains Item(1, 6), Item(2, 5) and Item(3, 5).

If I do this imperatively, I can consume my items while they have the same id, backing them up in a temporary collection, and deduplicate this collection when encountering an item with a different id.

If I use collect to first group the items by id, I will consume all the data at once before moving to the next operation, and I need to avoid that.

Comment: Try searching stream filter for deduplication and collect at the end.

Comment: A small code snippet would help. Because right now i'm not completely sure what you want to achieve. Throw some elements out of the list based on some internal fields is easy with filters, but i don't understand how the ID comes into play here.

Comment: What's the final form you want the data to take?

Comment: @Timmeey here you are

Comment: @shmosel it needs to be a stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but using the [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library, you should be able to [`collapse()`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#collapse-java.util.function.BiPredicate-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) adjacent elements like this:

```
items.collapse((a, b) -> a.id() == b.id(), (a, b) -> a.price() < b.price() ? b : a)
```

Answer (score 2):

For most cases of that kind, a temporary storage, like a `Map`, is inevitable. After all, it’s the map’s efficient lookup algorithm that allows to identify the group each element belongs to. Also, it’s possible that the first group contains the first and the very last element of the source stream and the only way to find out whether this is the case, is iterating the entire source stream. This might not be true for your special case of pre-sorted data, but the API doesn’t provide a way to exploit this for a grouping operation. And it wouldn’t play nicely with parallel Stream support, if it existed.

But consider the [`groupingBy` collector accepting a downstream `Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) which allows you to reduce the groups to their final result in-place. If it is a true reduction, you can use, e.g. [`reducing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#reducing-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) as downstream collector. This allows you to collect the elements into a `Map<Id, Reduced>` rather than `Map<Id, List<Elem>>`, so you don’t collect into `List`s that have to be reduced afterwards.

For any similar case, if you can describe the follow-up operation as a `Collector`, its processing will indeed start right when encountering the first element of a group. Note that there are other combining `Collector`s like [`mapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) and [`collectingAndThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-). Java 9 will also add `filtering` and `flatMapping`, so you can express a lot of typical `Stream` operations in form of a downstream collector. For convenience, [this collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#reducing-U-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) combines a mapping step with a follow-up reduction step.

Further processing of the groups can only be done after the full completion of the grouping, by accessing `Map.values()`. If the final result is supposed to be a `Collection`, it’s not necessary to stream over it again, as the existing collection operations are sufficient, e.g. you can use `new ArrayList<>(map.values())` if you need a `List` rather than an unspecific `Collection`.

---

If your concern is that the operation should not be performed until the caller commences a terminal operation on the final Stream, you can use an operation like this:

```
public Stream<ResultType> stream() {
    return StreamSupport.stream(() -> items.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(classificationFunc,
                Collectors.reducing(id, mappingFunc, reductionFunc)))
            .values().spliterator(),
        Spliterator.SIZED, false);
}
```

Comment: *After all, it’s the map’s efficient lookup algorithm that allows to identify the group each element belongs to.* Since the source is sorted by key, it *theoretically* could be grouped without a map structure.

Comment: @shmosel: I was considering the statement “I need to deduplicate them based on conditions on other fields” which makes it unclear whether exploiting the already sorted nature is possible. However, the collectors provided by the JRE don’t support this anyway.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for your explanations. As shmosel pointed out, I provided this information because I though it might be exploited somehow (and it does while dealing with the imperative version). But it don't have to. The fact is that I need to return the resulting stream at some point, and I wanted the data to be processed only once and by the caller.

Comment: It’s possible to implement such algorithm, but it’s not provided by the JRE classes. I added a demonstration, how laziness can be achieved even with the builtin grouping operation, as much as this operation allows.

Comment: @Holger I didn't think to the stream factory taking a Supplier, that's great ! There is still one drawback that I wish to avoid (but I think we've reach the limit of it) : this will work well on most cases when the final amount of data is "reasonable", but it won't be efficient on large amount of data since collect has to store everything in RAM.

Comment: Indeed, that’s only possible to avoid, if you exploit the sorted nature, which requires a custom collector (or spliterator) or a 3rd party library solution.

Comment: @Holger I'm interested in how you would implement this custom collector

Comment: shmosel’s answer points to the StreamEx library, which is open source. Afaik, it’s `collapse` implementation is based on a custom spliterator, so looking at its source will show, how you can implement such an operation.